# Execute things before and/or after an interactive command

Tags: powershell

In Bash, I can use a trap on `DEBUG` signal to execute things before any command, and the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable to execute things after any interactive command.

In Zsh, I can use `preexec`/`preexec_functions` and `precmd`/`precmd_functions` for respectively the same things.

Is there a way to do that in PowerShell?

Comment: In PowerShell, the prompt is actually generated by a [PowerShell function (called, naturally enough, `prompt`)](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-prompt.html). That can be made to run what you want any time the PowerShell prompt is displayed, which would (I guess) be what you consider "after any interactive command".

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that uses an Invoke-Command or otherwise:

```bsh
Function Invoke-Debug {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)
        [Scriptblock[]]$Scriptblock
    )

    Before {
        #Before all code
    }

    Process {
        ForEach ($SB in $Scriptblock) {
            #Before each code
            Invoke-Command -Scriptblock $SB
            #After each code
        }
    }

    End {
        #After all code
    }
}
```

You could do it many other ways, as well.

With this, do you run your commands like this:

```bsh
Invoke-Debug -Scriptblock {#Your code here}
```

Or:

```bsh
$Scriptblock = {#Your code here}
Invoke-Debug -Scriptblock $Scriptblock
```

Comment: But this would require the end-user to actually type `Invoke-Debug ...` right? I'd like it to be transparent, for each command he enters in the interactive session/

Comment: @pawamoy It would.  Alternatively, you could add a ```Set-PSDebug``` to your users’ profiles.  You could also check out ```New-Event```.